# Access H2 Database from application contained in a JAR File

Tags: java, h2

I have an application which uses H2 database and the following Connection String:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:file:data/sample", "sa", "");
```

It works quite well under Eclipse, however if I package the Java Desktop application in a JAR file, it cannot find the H2 Database in data/sample any more. Here is the running directory:

```
application.jar
data |
     sample.h2.db
```

And here is how I try to execute the application:

```
java -classpath .; -jar application.jar
```

A SQLException is raised as no tables are found. Any hint how could I have my Connection running into Eclipse and within a JAR file ? 
Please note that as requirement I should not use an absolute path for the database but a relative path, because the database folders are unzipped along with the jar files by the Application Installer.

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace please? And in your classpath I don't see the `h2.jar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some possible causes of error I can think about :

- the database is empty. You might have populate it when building the application under eclipse but when launching from the jar file, you hit an empty one : control that using H2 console, and either populate the database at launch time if it is empty or do put an fully initialized one along with the jar.
- as you give a relative path to your database, the actual path depends on the current working directory. This is rather unusual and error prone. You'd better give an absolute path, that could be found in an environment variable or in a java system property : it's still configurable but more *explicit*

For the second possibility, H2 automatically creates a new database if it does not find it. To avoid this automatic creation when the path is wrong, you can add `;IFEXISTS=TRUE` to the url : `"jdbc:h2:file:data/sample;IFEXISTS=TRUE"`. But avoid relative paths if you can ...

Comment: Thanks, I've found out that I made a mistake in the classpath when I first launched the application. So what happened is that the DB file got overwritten (re-created). I'll add to the path the IFEXISTS=TRUE argument